# function not taken into account (w. makefile)

Tags: c++, makefile, testcase, doctest

**==> I tried to resume a long long code, so all the other functions than the concerned ones are already tested and are working! All the #include are okay too**

an Ant is :

```
#ifndef ANT_HPP
#define ANT_HPP

class Ant{
public:
    Ant(Coord a, int n); //constructor: the coordonate of the ant, and its number
    void deplace(Coord a); //an ant goes to coordonates a

    Coord fCoord; //the coordonates of the Ant
    int fNum; //a Number attributed to each ant };
#endif
```

So, I have this in Ant.cpp :

```
void Ant::deplace(Coord a){ fCoord = a; }
```

and the test (with doctest) are perfectely working:

```
TEST_CASE("test fourmis : "){   
    Ant f = Ant(Coord{2,3}, 3);
    f.deplace(Coord{11,12});
    CHECK(f.coord() == Coord{11,12}); }
```

In an other file I am trying to make an Ant goes from Place a to Place b like:

```
void deplaceAnt(Ant f, Place a, Place b) {
      p1.takeAnt();            //take an Ant away of a Place p1
      f.deplace(p2.coord());   //the function that is not working :(
      p2.putAnt(f);            // put an Ant in a Place p2 }
```

place.hpp is like :

```
#ifndef PLACE_HPP
#define PLACE_HPP
#include "Ant.hpp"

class Place{
public:
    Place(Coord x);  //constructor : create a Place from a Coordonate
    int numAnt;  //the number of the Ant on the Place
    bool isAnt;  //if there is an Ant or not
    Coord Pcoord; //Coord of the Place }
#endif
```

Here is the the test that doesn't work:

```
TEST_CASE("Place test : "){
    Place q = Place(Coord{11,12});
    Place p = Place(Coord{2,6});
    Ant f = Ant(Coord{1,2}, 3)

    q.putAnt(f);
    deplaceAnt(f, q, p);

    // f{1,2} must go from q{3,4} to p{2,6}
    CHECK(f.fCoord == p.coord());
    CHECK(q.isAnt == false);
    CHECK(p.isAnt == true); }
```

**And here is the message after compilation:**

```
TEST CASE:  test Place :

place.cpp:206: ERROR: CHECK( f.fCoord == p.coord() ) is NOT correct!
  values: CHECK( (1,2) == (2,6) )

place.cpp:207: ERROR: CHECK( q.isAnt == false ) is NOT correct!
  values: CHECK( true == false )

place.cpp:209: ERROR: CHECK( p.isAnt == true ) is NOT correct!
  values: CHECK( false == true )

===============================================================================
[doctest] test cases:      5 |      4 passed |      1 failed |      0 skipped
[doctest] assertions:     67 |     62 passed |      5 failed |
[doctest] Status: FAILURE!
```

**I want to know why the function is working in a file.cpp and not in an other. +There are others functions in Ant.cpp (that I didn't show here) that I re-used in Place.cpp and there were np with them... strange isn't it?**

Comment: You're using the same header guard name in your `Ant` header: `#ifndef PLACE_HPP`. Consider using `#pragma once` instead as common compilers support it.

Comment: oops my bad I ctr+c/v this part of my code badly. :o

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
void deplaceAnt(Ant f, Place a, Place b)
```

takes the parameters by value, meaning they are *copies*. Changes to these objects won't affect the original objects. You need to pass them by reference instead:

```
void deplaceAnt(Ant& f, Place& a, Place& b)
```

So you're making changes to the original objects rather than copies.

Comment: When I compile I have the following error : `error: call of overloaded 'deplaceAnt(Ant&, Place&, Place&)' is ambiguous`

Comment: @piau I'm assuming you only have a single `deplaceAnt` function. Did you change the function in the header and in the cpp? You need to change it everywhere.

Comment: oh yes it is finally working, thanks you very much! you helped me a lot :)